# Dishwasher - valve on water pipe designed as not to be opened

Tags: water, dishwasher, valve, uk

I'm connecting dishwasher in my new place and I'm baffled by the valve on the pipe. I swear it looks like it was designed so that it won't be opened. Unless it doesn't turn... but this is ball type.

In case it helps: I'm in the UK. Not being British I can't think of any way to open it...
Help?
[image]

There is small protrusion from the side of the white pipe which prevents me from turning. Weird, to say the least.

Comment: The photo is washed out so it's hard to see exactly what's going on, but it looks like there might be a small screw on top of the shut-off lever, can you take that screw off, remove the lever, and turn it 180 degrees so it's no longer blocked?

Comment: I agree Johnny , that or the Handel is 90 out. +

Comment: Even if that protrusion wasn't there it looks as though the screw-on hose connection would also be too close to allow the lever to turn. Can you push or pull it up or down at all?

Comment: Looks like that valve is a quarter-turn mini lever ball valve, and currently turned off. Push the orange lever towards the grey pipe. They have a stop on them so that they can only move 90 degrees in either direction.

Comment: @Johnny - You were correct. After removing the lever I was able to open the valve. I was actually thinking it was something like this, but after removing the screw the lever would not budge, even after applying pliers and pulling up (carefully, so as not to damage anything). So gave up and asked about it here. Thank you for confirmation.
If you can convert your comment to answer I will mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The photo is washed out so it's hard to see exactly what's going on, but it looks like there might be a small screw on top of the shut-off lever, can you take that screw off, remove the lever, and turn it 180 degrees so it's no longer blocked?

Answer (score 0):

It's a washing machine / dishwasher valve, probably with a check valve judging by its size - similar to http://www.screwfix.com/p/washing-machine-valve-with-check-valve-15mm-x/27660

Usually they open with the handle pointing **away** from 3/4" / service side.

It looks pretty corroded so you may struggle. You could replace with another compression fit (it's a 15mm to 3/4") or use a push-fit alternative
 http://www.johnguest.com/speedfit/product/valves/appliance-tap/

If you go down the push fit route and the existing white pipe is plastic, you need to cut the pipe square with a the proper tool and use a pipe insert.

Comment: It's very similar, but not quite the same valve as the one you linked. Thank you for the answer, though. I may replace it at some point, because my idea of a shut off valve is not in the least similar to the idea that's implemented in my new home... Unless it was one to build as cheap one as possible, not the one that works well in an emergency...